# Why is my decorator not working when using the alternative to @ syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm making a tool for my command line programs, and I will not argue the use of it on this question. The fact is, I use decorators to assign functions to a "token". My code works perfectly as intended when using the @decorator syntax, but fails to do anything when I use the alternative (forgive me, as I don't know the name). Below is the relevant function for the decorator:

```py
def __add_command(self, command):
    for name in command.names:
        if name in self:
            raise self.CommandExists(
                f"Name or alias assigned to function {command.funct.__name__} is duplicate: {name}"
            )
        else:
            self[name] = command
    self.commands_no_aliases.append(command.names[0])

def add_command(self, *names, does=None):
    def inner_fn(funct):
        self.__add_command(Command(funct, names, does or "No information provided for this command"))
        return funct

    return inner_fn
```

[Here's all the code if you would like to see more.](https://gist.github.com/HavenSelph/a0628a21d09ae508bdee8753dac448aa)

Here's the code where I attempted to use the alternative decorator syntax, and the working @ syntax.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    COMMANDMODULE = Commands()


    @COMMANDMODULE.add_command("hi", does="prints hello world")
    def hi():
        print("Hello world!")


    @COMMANDMODULE.add_command("echo", "repeat", "print", does="prints any passed arguments")
    def echo(*args):
        for x in args:
            print(str(x))


    @COMMANDMODULE.add_command("echotwice", "repeattwice", "printtwice", does="prints any passed arguments; but twice")
    def echotwice(*args):
        print(args)
        for x in args:
            print(str(x), str(x), sep="\n")


    def add(a, b, *args, print=True):
        x = sum((a, b, *args))
        if print:
            print(x)
        else:
            return x


    add = COMMANDMODULE.add_command(add, "add", does="returns the sum of all passed arguments (integers required)")
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                last = COMMANDMODULE.execute(input(">>> "))
                if last[0] == 0:
                    pass
            except COMMANDMODULE.NoValidInput as e:
                print(e)
            except COMMANDMODULE.ParseError as e:
                print(e)
            except COMMANDMODULE.NoSuchCommand as e:
                print(e)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Now, running this in debug mode shows that the function "add" is never added to my list of commands. Here is a screenshot of that:

[image: Screenshot of no function called add]

In that screenshot you can see that the rest of my code works as intended. So I would like to know why

```
add = COMMANDMODULE.add_command(add, "add", does="returns the sum of all passed arguments (integers required)")
```

does not work in this scenario.

I really don't know what to try past looking up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator), which I did.
[image: Just a screenshot of the above documentation.]

I tried exactly this, and it seems to just ignore my inner_function which I do not understand. The intended behavior would clearly be to function exactly like the @add_command, but yet it doesn't.

I'm going to be really annoyed if I screwed something up syntax wise, but I appreciate any and all help. Feel free to ask for more info if there's something I haven't provided. Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot the `__call__` method from the decorator definition.

Comment: Remember, the decorator returns a function that should be passed the function it's going to wrap; so you need to actually call the returned function. `add = COMMANDMODULE.add_command("add", does="returns the sum of all passed arguments (integers required)")(add)`. `add` is not an extra argument to pass to `COMMANDMODULE.add_command`; instead, it's what you pass to the function `COMMANDMODULE.add_command` returns, and the new function _that_ returns is what becomes the decorated/wrapped function you actually use.

Comment: @FerhatMousavi Can you explain that in more detail or link the proper documentation? That isn't actually the issue here but I'm curious as to it's use-case. Thanks for your really fast response either way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks Charles, that's the issue. I guess I didn't have a good enough understanding of how decorators work to catch that. Thank you!

Comment: @HavenSelph simple class decorator definition is `class MyDecorator:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
     
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
 
        # We can add some code
        # before function call
 
        self.function(*args, **kwargs)
 
        # We can also add some code
        # after function call.`

Comment: @FerhatMousavi Ah I see, thanks! I can see that actually as an alternative to how I handle things with my script. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for pointing out that it was in-fact a syntax issue. Decorators return their inner function meaning that add_command actually returned my inner_function and I never called that. The fix was simple:

```py
add = COMMANDMODULE.add_command(add, "add", does="returns the sum of all passed arguments (integers required)")
```

Needed to be changed to:

```py
add = COMMANDMODULE.add_command("add", does="returns the sum of all passed arguments (integers required)")(add)
```